# FTP (21) Not Listening - GCP/Debian 8/ProFTPD

Tags: ftp, proftpd

I just started learning Linux about a few months ago so apologize if I am missing something easy. I have a Debian 8 server on Google Cloud Platform that I have setup it up to run a Wordpress multisite install. Server works great but I wanted to FTP all data from my current host; Host Gator. I was going to use GoodSync to do FTP to FTP data sync. (Side note, Host Gator have prevent me from creating a server back up due to disk size limitations and CPU resource/php timeout limitations prevent me from using Wordpress plugins to do a migration.)

So I have the FTP working on Host Gator's server but when I try to set up the FTP on my server, I noticed that FTP port 21 is not listening. I already opened up port 21 specifically on GCP via Network - Firewall. I did scanned the ports with a phone app, port 21 used to report back as blocked but now it's closed so I think the network side is fine.

This is what I get when I run this script to see if ProFTPD is running:

```
ps -ef | grep proftpd
proftpd    570     1  0 Sep25 ?        00:00:01 proftpd: (accepting connections)
```

I see that ProFTPD is running and listening on port 2222 (tcp6 per netstat) but that doesn't do me any good as GoodSync only allows for port 21 FTP connections.

Finally, I did review the ProFTPD configuration and it's shows port 21 there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide the `proftpd.conf` (sanitized for sensitive info) that you are using?

Comment: Here is the proftpd.conf: [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1az1NemJlkUj6UaCoJ54taVmaoQaud1r84M-UE2W3H90/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: The config doesn't show any `Port 2222` -- although maybe the `Include` directives are pulling in other files which use `Port 2222`.  Interesting.  Can you connect to port 21, from that GCP instance itself, _e.g._ `ftp localhost 21` or `ftp localhost 2222`?  If so, then the issue is probably in the networking setup somewhere; if not, the issue might be with the ProFTPD configuration in some fashion.

Comment: I tried over the weekend connecting to the server internally via port 21 and it didn't work. I think I'll just manually reupload all the files and call it day.